# Error 500: java.lang.StackOverflowError in WAS 7

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, websphere, websphere-7

I'm trying to get the world's simplest JSF app running on a Websphere server. The app consists of two xhtml files and the web.xml file. The app compiles, builds, and installs without any problems. When I try to view the pages in my browser I get:

Error 500: java.lang.StackOverflowError

Nothing else shows up on the page nor in the logs. I've been googling for hours but can't find a solution.

Here is my web.xml file:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And here is the JSF page:

```
<f:view>
<h:form>
    <h:panelGrid columns="1">
        <h:outputLabel value="Carrier" />

        <h:outputLabel value="Item Number: " />

        <h:outputLabel value="Postal Code: " />

        <h:outputLabel value="Quantity: " />

    </h:panelGrid>  

</h:form>
</f:view>
```

This is such a simple app I can't imagine why it wont run. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Oh, let me add the app runs perfectly on Glassfish and Webspere CE just not on Websphere Express v7. Of course I need it to run on Websphere Express v7.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Apparently the *actual* view file does not have the `.jspx` extension, but the `.xhtml` extension. Hence the `FacesServlet` will run in an infinite loop calling itself everytime which ultimately results in the memory stack being overflowed.</strike>

To fix this, you need to **remove** this entry from `web.xml`:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.jspx</param-value>
</context-param>
```

It defaults to `.xhtml` already.

I also suggest to remove this mapping:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Stick to using `.xhtml` extension in URLs like so http://localhost:8080/context/page.xhtml.

---

**Update**: my mistake. WAS 7 does *not* support JSF 2.0 at all. It supports JSF 1.2 only. See also the [WAS documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/tweb_jsf.html). You need JSP files instead of Facelets (XHTML) files. You also cannot utilize JSF 2.0 advantages.

To get JSF 2.0 to work in WAS 7, you need to bundle it yourself in `/WEB-INF/lib` of the webapp and to configure the WAS classloader policies. See also [this link](http://www.manorrock.com/online/wiki/jsf/Websphere7)

> Even though Websphere 7 does not formally support JSF 2.0 you can get it to work in a degraded mode. Follow the steps below to get it to work on your version of Websphere 7.
>
> - Upgrade to at least version 7.0.0.13
> - Ship the Mojarra JAR files in your WEB-INF/lib directory
> - Set the WAR classloader to PARENT_LAST
> - Set the EAR classloader to PARENT_LAST and APPLICATION
>
> Note the degraded mode means you are NOT going to be able to use @Resource or any JPA annotations. If you think you need support for it contact your IBM representative.
>
> Note it will process @PostConstruct and @PreDestroy.

Comment: Thanks BalusC. I did have .xhtml as the param-value and was getting the same error. I changed it to .jspx after reading comments on another site. Regardless of what value I seem to put in the context-param/param-value I still get stackoverflow error.

Comment: What extension does your actual file have? (it should be `.xhtml`) What JARs do you have in `/WEB-INF/lib`? (for WAS you should actually have no one) How does your `faces-config.xml` root declaration look like? (for JSF 2.0 you need a JSF 2.0 compatible one)

Comment: There are no jar files and no faces-config.xml either. I'm just trying to get a page to display with some basic jsf tags. All my pages/files have .xhtml extension. There is no processing or logic just a simple page with some tags. What could it the problem be? I've tried everything and as far as I can tell all my code is correct.

Answer (score 1):

If, for some reason, you need to use **JSF 1.2** instead of **2.0**,

you can try adding [**Facelets**](http://download.java.net/maven/1/com.sun.facelets/jars/) library to the project.

And add the following to **faces-config.xml**:

```
<faces-config>
    .
    .
    <application>
        <view-handler>com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler</view-handler>
    </application>
    .
    .
</faces-config>
```

Now you can use **.xhtml** instead of **.jsp** under JSF 1.2